# How to import UTF8 table in another encoding(win1251, SQL_ASCII) with COPY()?

Tags: sql, postgresql, encoding, encode, postgresql-9.5

**Prehistory:** Hello, i saw many questions about encoding in postgres, but.
I have UFT8 table, and i'm using COPY function to import that table in CSV, and i need to make COPY with different encodings like WIN1251 and SQL_ASCII.

**Problem:** When in table i have characters that not supported in WIN1251/SQL_ASCII, i will got classic error

```
character with byte sequence 0xe7 0xb0 0xab in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "WIN1251"
```

I tried using "set client_encoding/ convert / convert_to" - no success.

**Main question:** Is there any way to do this without error using sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is simply no way to convert 簫 into Windows-1252, so you can forget about that.

If you set the client encoding to `SQL_ASCII`, you will be able to load the data into an `SQL_ASCII` database, but that is of little use, since the database does not recognize it as a character, but three meaningless bytes above 127.